# How to Return a custom axios response based on response's error code

Tags: javascript, vue.js, error-handling, vuejs2, axios

I'm trying to make a global error handling in my vue application. I have a api.service.js file that includes my axios and, creates and my get,post functions:

```
/**
 * Service to call HTTP request via Axios
 */
const ApiService = {
  init(apiBaseUrl) {
    Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);
    Vue.axios.defaults.baseURL = apiBaseUrl;
  },

  /**
   * Set the default HTTP request headers
   */

  setHeader() {
    Vue.axios.defaults.headers.common[
      "Authorization"
    ] = `Bearer ${JwtService.getToken()}`;
  },

  setHeaderwToken(token) {
    Vue.axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
  },

  /**
   * Send the GET HTTP request
   * @param resource
   * @param slug
   * @returns {*}
   */
   get(resource, slug = "") {
    var myBlob = new Blob([], {type:'text/plain'});
    var init = { status: 200, statusText: "" };
    var myResponse = new Response(myBlob, init);
   return Vue.axios.get(`${resource}/${slug}`)
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error.response.status == 401) {
        //401 response
        if (resource != "CheckToken") {
          // request isNot checktoken & 401 response, check if token is valid?
          Vue.axios
            .get("CheckToken") 
            .then((CheckTokenResponse) => {
              console.log("CheckToken response");
              if (CheckTokenResponse.data == "OK") {
                //token valid + 401 response
                init = { status: 401, statusText: "noAuthorityValid" };
                myResponse = new Response(myBlob, init);
                console.log(CheckTokenResponse);
                console.log("//token valid + 401 response");
                console.log(myResponse);
                return myResponse;
              } else {
                init = { status: 401, statusText: "noTokenValid" };
                myResponse = new Response(myBlob, init);
                console.log(CheckTokenResponse);
                console.log("//token NOT valid + 401 response");
                return myResponse;
              }
            })
            .catch(() => {
              init = { status: 401, statusText: "noTokenValid" };
              myResponse = new Response(myBlob, init);          
              return myResponse;
            });
        } else {
          //request is CheckToken + 401 response
          init = { status: 401, statusText: "noTokenValid" };
          myResponse = new Response(myBlob, init);
          console.log(error);
          console.log("//request is CheckToken + 401 response");
          return myResponse;
        }
      } else {
        // != 401 response
        console.log(error);
        console.log("!= 401 response");
        return error; 
      }
    });
  },

};

export default ApiService;
```

In my Vue component, I'm calling my ApiService:

```
  ApiService.get("MyFunction")
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("MyFunction " + response);
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("MyFunction " + error);
    });
},
```

[image: the browser's console log goes like this:]

I tried to create a custom response (myResponse) and return it but it returns as **undefined**
(I guess that's a wrong approach)
What i want to achieve is,
when a function is called and return an error code from api,
(500, 401, 404..)
i want to catch it,
and if it's 401, then i want to call "CheckToken" function and then if, CheckToken returns "OK" i want to return "noAuthorityValid" (means token is valid but that function is unauthorized.), CheckToken is not OK, then i want to return noTokenValid and i want to do it in my vue component where i call my function:

```
  ApiService.get("MyFunction")
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("MyFunction " + response);
// if (response.statusText == noAuthorityValid)
{
// show snackbar("you are not authorized for this function")
}
})
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log("MyFunction " + error);
    });
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't do it with api.service.js so i created a walk-around.
I imported axios in every component i need an axios call;

```
import axios from "axios";
```

then i used axios like this:

```
 axios({
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
          Accept: "application/json",
        },
        url: "MyFunction",
        method: "get",
      })
      .then((response) => {....}
```

And then, in my top component's (top parent) created function, i used axios.interceptors.response like this:

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
      (response) => {
        return response;
      },
      (error) => {
        this.handleError(error);
        return Promise.reject(error);
      }
    );
```

and this is my handleError function:

```
handleError(error) {
  if (error.response.status == 401) {
    if (error.response.data.includes("expiredToken")) {
      this.showSnackbar("Token is expired");
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (!window.location.href.includes("login")) {
          this.$router.push({ name: "login" }).then(() => {
            this.$store.dispatch(LOGOUT); //PURGES user data,
          });
        }
      }, 2000);
    } else if (
      error.response.data.includes(
        "UnauthorizedFunction"
      )
    ) {
      this.showSnackbar("You are not authorized for this function ");
    } else {
      this.showSnackbar("Error occured.");
    }
  } else {
  this.showSnackbar("Error occured.");
  }
}
```

This stupid problem took my 2.5 days..